# Best way to save active and not-active items for Tableau

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have a DB of temperatures in RedShift.

The fact table contains the following columns:

1. measurement_date
2. measurement_type
3. measurement_category
4. temperature
5. humidity
6. brightness
7. etc...

On some days (due to hardware problems) measurement may be missing.

I would like to be able to efficiently see in Tableau which days I had no measurements on, for which measurement_types and for which measurement_categories.

Could you please suggest what would be the "best practice approach" to implement something like this in Tableau?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tableau, you can check for null values with ZN expression (see [here](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v6.1/public/online/en-us/id21fb108b-00ca-4ec6-a8c4-a018d2ed8332.html)) or ISNULL expression (see [here](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v6.1/public/online/en-us/id9749c42e-bbc3-449b-a096-b386c85d2e81.html)).

Then, you can create Calculated Fields for the subset of Null or Non-Null values, with this kind of structure

```
IF ZN([temperature]) = 0 THEN "show" END
```

or

```
IF ISNULL([temperature]) THEN "show" END
```

This gives you a new variable for which you can filter.

You can also string multiple variables in order to get more specific scenerios:

```
IF ISNULL([temperature]) AND [measurement_type] = "whatever" THEN "show" END
```

[Read more about it here.](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/filtering-multiple-dimensions-using-parameters)

Comment: thanks a lot! One more question - when I miss a measurement, there is no record in my fact table at all. Particularly, I have no NULL value I could subset to 0. Any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: You may then have to do some logic with the date... In Tableau one option is DATEDIFF: http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/difference-dates-one-date-field So you would create a column which is the difference in date from one row to the row before, and then calculate if that difference is more than one day.